# Assuming the conformal factor is radially decreasing, prove or disprove the uniqueness of geodesic joining origin and points on the boundary of ball

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Let $u$ be a radially decreasing function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$. We consider the metric $g=e^{2u}\delta$ where $\delta$ is the standard Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $B_r$ be the ball centered at the origin with Euclidean radius $r$. Then for any $x \in \partial B_r$, by direct computation we know that the line segment connecting the origin and $x$ must be a geodesic. My question is that, is it true that the line segment joining the origin and $x$ is the unique geodesic connecting these two points?

Intuitively this is correct, because such line segment seems to be length minimizing. However, unfortunately I'm not be able to prove this....

I'm actually not very familiar with Riemannian geometry. Any ideas, comments or references will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be length minimizing, because it is the unique geodesic from the origin to $x$. In particular, any ray from the origin is geodesic so we know all the geodesics from the origin. Since the shortest path from the origin to $x$ is a geodesic and there is only one such geodesic, it must be length minimizing.

Note that this does not mean that the shortest path from $x$ to $-x$ is necessarily a line segment through the origin. One could imagine the surface being shaped like a light bulb with the origin being the top of the bulb. If $x$ and $-x$ are on the threading, it's much shorter to go around the threading rather than go to the top and back down.

Comment: In particular, this is a property of radially symmetric metrics. It doesn't depend on them being conformally flat or the conformal factor decreasing.

Comment: Could you show why it is the unique geodesic from the origin to $x$? I know it is a geodesic, but I don't know how to show uniqueness.

Comment: Via the exponential map, there is a correspondence between geodesics emanating from the origin and unit tangent vectors. For each unit tangent vector, there is a geodesic given by the ray based at the origin in that direction. As such, those are all of the geodesics and there is only one that reaches $x$.

Comment: Sorry I still could not get it. Why there cannot exist other unit tangent vectors along the direction of which the corresponding geodesic reaches $x$? Also how would you exclude cut locus?

Comment: I suppose I should say why the shortest path from the origin to $x$ is given by a geodesic at all, since we don't assume that the metric is complete.  It's an ugly argument, but a proof of this can be found here. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317523/minimizing-geodesics-in-incomplete-riemannian-manifolds/317547#317547

Comment: To respond to your second question, the metric is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we know that the rays based at the origin are geodesics. In Euclidean space, there is only a single ray from the origin which passes through $x$. Every other ray does not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I do appreciate it. Actually I don't have trouble in understanding the existence of minimizing geodesic between $0$ and $x$ even if the metric is not complete,  but I do have trouble in understanding why there are no other geodesics connecting $0$ and $x$. Think about a sphere, and $0$ is the coordinate of the south pole, and $x$ be the coordinate of some point on the sphere. Even thought $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Euclidean space, with the metric $e^{2u}\delta$ the manifold is not flat.

Comment: As for the cut locus, this same reasoning shows that the origin has no cut locus. It's possible for the cut locus to be non-empty at other points, but since there is a unique geodesic from the origin to a point $x$ and the shortest paths from the origin are given by geodesics (even when the metric is not complete), this shows there cannot be any cut locus at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107155/discussion-between-gabe-k-and-student).